# MetaUML -- generate image as output

Tags: graphics, metapost, output

I'm planning to use MetaUML to automatically generate UML diagrams (as images) and display them.

I found that there is an utility, mptopdf, that helps generating the output as a PDF file:

```
mptopdf example.mp
```

Is there any way that I can generate the output as an image file (png/jpg, or any format)? Please suggest. Am entirely new to this.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that you don't have to (and shouldn't) sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) installed, you can easily convert the pdf to any other image format:

```
convert -trim +repage example.pdf example.png
```

You can replace `.png` by [any other supported format](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).
The `-trim +repage` option removes unnecessary whitespace surrounding the image and sets the canvas size to the trimmed image. You can also add `-density 300` (or any other number) to specify the dpi of the resulting raster image. For example,

```
convert -density 600 -trim +repage example.pdf -resize 200% example.png
```

Comment: This is wonderful! With IM I can even scale up the image size. Thanks!

However, I'll be using this in context of a web application. I was wondering if the output image could be generated "directly". Becasue, creating a PDF and then converting it requires both time and space.

Comment: I have never used MetaUML, so I can't tell. Compiling the metapost to ps instead of pdf and converting from there might be a bit faster (be sure to do some real world test). But basically I think this is the process that is usually used to get an image file out of TeX code.

Comment: In case someone was as clueless as I was on where to put `-density` and `-resize`, it's `convert -density 600 -trim +repage example.pdf -resize 200% example.png`. Higher sampling density makes the output picture sharper, which is needed when resize up.